# Make the header row not clickable (don't highlight) the header

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help,

How can my jQuery code below be modified such that it will disallow (prevent) the user from selecting (highlighting) the top table header row? As it stands right now, each row in the table is selectable.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$("#data tr").click(function() {

    var selected = $(this).hasClass("highlight");

    $("#data tr").removeClass("highlight");

    if (!selected) { $(this).addClass("highlight"); }

});
```

Here is the HTML markup:

```
<table id="data" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
    <tr>
        <th>header1</th>
        <th>header2</th>
        <th>header3</th>
        <th>header4</th>
        <th>header5</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
        <td>data</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Put it in a `<thead>` where it belongs, then put the rest of the rows in a `<tbody>`. When you do  your DOM selection, narrow it down to the rows in the `<tbody>`, like this: `$("#data tbody tr")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your html or use: `$("#data tr:not(:first)").click(function() {`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `:gt()` selector on the first line:

```
$("#data tr:gt(0)").click(function () {
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/uxvaU/)**

This binds the click event to all but the first row.